# How to log the history of creation and deletion of specific entries in the ignite cache?

Tags: ignite

I have an abnormal deletion of certain entries from my ignite server.
I want to know, why it is deleted.
Is there a way to track the entry history?
Can I log when creating and removing entries?
Thank you.

Comment: please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

By default there is no entry history.

You can track creation and deletion by enabling [cache events](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/events) and registering a listener.